# Click event not fired when clicking on canvas in Chrome during animation (works in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, addeventlistener, requestanimationframe

[My janky flying rat game](https://purplemongrel.github.io/rat-game/)

[repository on github](https://github.com/PurpleMongrel/rat-game)

Working on this janky little flying rat game.

I'm planning on having the rat shoot cheese bullets in the direction of the mouse pointer. I am adding click event listeners - currently on window, but will be on canvas afterwards.

The click event currently prints the mouse position to console

When I open the game, the click event fires and prints to console regardless of where I click.

Once the canvas switches from the introduction "page" to the actual game, the click event stops firing when clicking on the canvas - yet it keeps firing click events outside of the canvas.

This issue happens in Chrome. In Firefox there is no issue.

I also noticed that when looking at elements in chrome dev tools, once the introduction page ends, and the game starts, the body block (in "elements section") starts flickering. I'm thinking this may be related.

I can't see what is so different about how the introduction page canvas and the gameplay are animated/drawn to cause this issue.

Comment: A minimal code sample of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 my apologies - I imagined seeing the code in dev tools and "inspect" would be enough. Adding a link to Github repository in my question. Feel free to recommend a better way to share code.

Comment: Try to produce an [MCVE] (only a few line of code should be able to reproduce the issue) and include it in a StackSnippet: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: As for the blinking it's basically your [`State` constructor](https://github.com/PurpleMongrel/rat-game/blob/a6338dac3add292185599f2ead704c00e1c1a511/BobDilo_Game.js#L471) which does a lot of useless work and very slow work every frame among which it reappends the canvas in the body. You should rewrite your State.update method so that it doesn't create a new State but instead correctly updates itself.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for that suggestion. I think I'll keep creating new states for each frame, but drastically minimize what the state holds and create separate classes for other things like the canvas. I expect it might solve my original click event issue.